# "This is an invalid webresource request" no longer an issue when resetting IE8 to default settings

Tags: asp.net, telerik, webresource.axd

Our production server has been logging the dreaded "This is an invalid webresource request" randomly. We use a lot of Telerik controls in this application and the issue would manifest itself to the user as missing background images for Telerik controls. I was able to reproduce the problem on the production server, but not in development.

I was able to solve the problem locally by resetting my instance of IE8 back to default setting, details in this [acticle](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318378).

So my question is what IE setting would possibly cause this and how can I avoid this problem in the future?  Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing this in chrome and firefox as well on a login control. It appears to be an issue with caching and I'm not sure it's just an IE issues more of an asp or server issue with the latest browser updates. http://forums.asp.net/t/1609380.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [scriptresource.axd 404 error in asp net 4 application - webresource works fine though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797435/scriptresource-axd-404-error-in-asp-net-4-application-webresource-works-fine-t)